# How to collapse and collapse in two different div sections based on two different button clicks?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have two buttons defined as below:

```
<button href="#select" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="collapse">
       Select
</button>

<button href="#add" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="collapse">
       Add
</button>
```

And I have two different div sections, defined as below:

```
<div id="select" class="collapse">
       Select your option
</div>

<div id="add" class="collapse">
        Add your option
</div>
```

When I click 'select' button, select div is collapsed.
After that if I click 'add' button, add div is collapsed just below the select div.

I want only one div to be shown at a time. If 'select' is clicked, select div should be collapsed and after that if user clicks 'add' div, select div should collapse in and only add div to be shown and vice versa.

I tried the above way but I am not achieving the expected result. Is there any way of achieving the behavior I want?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wrap both your div sections in a `.panel` and then in a parent container with an id. Then add the id as a `data-parent` attribute to your divs

```
<div id="parent">
  <div class="panel">
    <div id="select" class="collapse" data-parent="#parent">
      Select your option
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel">
    <div id="add" class="collapse panel" data-parent="#parent">
      Add your option
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/dszc5q5r/

Comment: Thank You so much @potatopeelings. It worked perfectly! :)